# eXist db behind Apache proxy - authentication

Tags: proxy, authentication, apache-2.4

I run an eXist db XML database which is proxied behind Apache. 
The setup of httpd.conf is as follows:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName foo
    ServerAlias foo

      ProxyRequests Off
      <Proxy *>
          Order deny,allow
          Allow from all
      </Proxy>

      ProxyPass        / http://localhost:8080/exist/apps/foo/
      ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/exist/apps/foo/

      ProxyTimeout 20

      ProxyPassReverseCookiePath /exist /
      ProxyPassReverseCookieDomain localhost foo

      RewriteEngine   on
      RewriteRule     ^/(.*)$     /$1   [PT]
  </VirtualHost>
```

That works pretty well. By accessing `http://localhost` with the browser I am *not* prompted to enter any password.
However, I now want to protect everything Apache might send or proxy (including the ErrorDocuments) with Basic User Authentication.

Therefore, I added

```
<Location />
     AuthUserFile /etc/users 
     AuthName "Beta testers only" 
     AuthType Basic 
     Require valid-user 
   </Location>
```

to httpd.conf.  (Obviously, it doesn't matter whether I do that in the VirtualHost section or outside of it.)

And this is where to problem starts.

When now trying to access localhost, I am prompted for a login twice: First, I have to enter the password for the Apache "Beta testers only". After I enter a legitimate login, I am then prompted by the browser for a second login. This time by eXist. However, trying to login with my eXist admin password leads in Firefox to endless waiting time without anything happening, while in Konqueror I get "Authentication Failed".

I simply can't understand why I am prompted to enter a password by eXist. Why does eXist care whether I have set a password in Apache or not?

Comment: this not solve your trouble but `Order deny allow` and `Allow from all` as been replace in apache 2.4

Comment: did you checked in your browser console network which file ask for auth ?

Comment: Thanks for that hint. However, I'm afraid the output is not particularly helpful. All I get in Firefox is `GET http://localhost/ [HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized 3ms]` after entering both passwords. BTW: If eXist is down, everything works fine. I enter the Apache password and see my costum error page.

Comment: What URL request is eXist issuing the password challenge for? I understand that you start by requesting `http://localhost/`, and after entering the password twice you're still looking at `http://localhost/`, but is that the URL eXist gets after you answer Apache's first challenge, or is it different?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by "the URL eXist gets". But according to Firefox' Web Console, the URL request remains the same throughout both password prompts: E.g. two times `http://localhost/` or `http://localhost/some_query.xq` or whatever. The response is always `[HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized xy ms]` And I'm pretty sure both passwords are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you see two dialogues I imagine is that Apache is doing basic auth and then forwarding some HTTP header for that to eXist, however eXist is rejecting the auth header because it doesn't have the same user database as Apache, and so it tries to re-authenticate.

If I understand correctly. You want to manage all authentication with Apache and leave eXist out of the authentication equation. Is that correct?

If so you might have a hard time doing this. eXist has it's own user database, if you want it to use the same one as Apache you will need to develop your own Realm plugin for eXist so that it can use the same user database as Apache (presumably you are just using PAM (and ultimately /etc/passwd)). If you are using LDAP, then eXist already has an LDAP Realm plugin so you could setup Apache and eXist to both use that.

Another option could be in eXist to just grant the guest user all access rights to everything but well that is a terrible idea.

I think you might be better to work the other way around, which is to NOT explicitly set Authentication in Apache for the eXist URL you are proxying. Instead you let eXist manage its authentication. eXist supports basic authentication perfectly well (even when proxied behind Apache), you just need to setup the users and permissions appropriately in eXist.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, you're right: I wanted to do all authentication in Apache, because this way I assumed that I have to set up authentication just once and avoid managing permissions both in eXist and in Apache. But if this is the easiest solution, so it be. (BTW: The eXist guest user already has access to the ressources in question. So, maybe even that doesn't help.)

Comment: You can modify the permissions in eXist to remove access by the guest user as you require.